# Changing title on DevicePicker makes text invisible

Tags: uwp

I'm only setting a `Title` on `DevicePicker.Appearance` and that results in a dialog in which everything is invisible. This is because the default property values for everything in `DevicePickerAppearance` is `null`. I would like to have the standard colors for this dialog. How can I get the values that are used by default when `DevicePicker.Appearance.Title` is not set?

```cs
    var picker = new DevicePicker();
    picker.Appearance.Title = "Fancy title";
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is because the default property values for everything in DevicePickerAppearance is null

By testing on my side, the default property values of `DevicePickerAppearance` that relative to color properties are all black. Which lead text invisible after the `Title` property was set.

But you could simply see out some color properties should be white, no other colors except black and white in the picker UI by default. Currently as a workaround  please set `ForegroundColor`,`SelectedForegroundColor`, `SelectedAccentColor` and `AccentColor` to white that will make the UI looks same with default as well the `Title` is customized.

```
DevicePickerAppearance Appearance = picker.Appearance;
picker.Appearance.Title = "Fancy title";
Appearance.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
Appearance.SelectedForegroundColor = Colors.White;
Appearance.SelectedAccentColor = Colors.White;
Appearance.AccentColor = Colors.White;
picker.Show(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 400));
```

Comment: Ah you're right about the values. `Color` is a struct making its default transparent black. Would this be considered a bug? I don't get why when you don't set the `Title` not all text is invisible.

Comment: @Wouter,It may be yes.  For the default property values issue, I have reported it by inner way. Thanks for feedback.